# Duplicate UUID found

Tags: firefox-addon

Some time a go I modify Firefox extension to my need and install it.
Few weeks ago Firefox automatically overwrite my modified extension with the original extension, a newer signed version. Probably because of the new signing policy:
https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2015/02/10/extension-signing-safer-experience/

I followed Firefox recommendation and upload for singing my modification so that it will be usable.
It failing on "Duplicate UUID found".
I tried to modify the UUID using http://www.somacon.com/p113.php didn't help.

How can I fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the install.rdf in your addon, then change the  to `myForkOfBLAH@me.com` and it will work